# Is the compatibility condition based Cauchy-Green strain used in FEM

Tags: finite-element-method

I'm currently studying continuum mechanics, with a view to solving some problems using the finite element technique.  I have studied, and understand, the proof of the compatibility conditions based on linearized strain and I am about to study the more mathematically sophisticated compatibility conditions based on the Cauchy-Green strain. However I wonder if this compatibility condition is used in the finite element method.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the compatibility equations are important is to ensure that the displacement of the structure is physically sensible, for example the deformed shape can not contain "holes" or other discontinuities in the material.

In the finite element method, the element shape functions are chosen to ensure compatible displacements across the element boundaries. The compatibility equations for the strains are then automatically satisfied - unless you have elements which intentionally contain singularities in the displacements and/or strains, e.g. to model crack propagation.

All of the above applies both to infinitesimal and finite strains.